# Are there any log4j or slf4j Appender frameworks that provide additional appenders

Tags: java, log4j, slf4j

While the core log4j and slf4j libraries come with a lot of good stuff, and i could build my own, but i was wondering if there are any libraries that ship with interesting appenders.

Most appenders seem to be bridges providing some connectivity to a particular service such as emailing messages or updating the NT event log. I am thinking of loggers that are more abstract and not middleware like, but equally useful to watchers of a live system.

**CRAZY IDEA OF AN APPENDER I THINK MIGHT BE USEFUL**

Logging is often useful but it can be a pain due to the shear volume of messages that really arent necessary because the associated request completed successfully. One idea ive had is wouldnt ie be useful to only log messages from http requests that throw some exception during processing. If the request did not fail then nothing would be added to the log. Naturally this sort of appender would require something to help control it.

```
BufferControl {
   FLUSH_NOW, // flush everything now in the buffer
   FLLUSH, // flush everything when BufferingLogger.commit() is called.
   CLEAR, // clear everything before
   CLEAR_ALL; /// all past and future messages are ignored
   IGNORE_AFTER; // ignore messages after this event.
   IGNORE_BEFORE, // ignore messages before
   CONTINUE, // just continue...
   etc etc..
}

// implements could tell the bufferingappender to log messages because some exception was thrown etc.    
LoggingEventWatcher {
   BufferControl look(LoggingEvent, BufferingAppender);
}

// every logging event is passed to the logging event watcher which 
BufferingAppender {
   start();
   reset(); // throw away everything in the buffer
   commit(); // use returned BufferControl to flush or reset etc.
   flush(); // unconditionally flush all messages now.
}
```

Imagine if one could log all messages only if a certain exception was logged. A controller would be needed to mark the start of a logging transaction, and whether to clear or flush depending on some condition.

Naturally some smarts would be necessary to reset the buffer and so on.

Comment: What kind of appenders are you talking about? Futhermore slf4j is an interface between different logging frameworks like commons-logging, log4j etc.

Comment: I don't really understand what you want: If you write some smart logic as the one you describe, then why restrict yourself to one (or two) Java logging frameworks? Such features should exist in some logging back-end (NT event log, DB storage of logs, ...) and the application should just push their log data to that.

Comment: @js i dont care which f/w offers me appenders, as its quite possible to use slf4j as a bridge between the two. I amhowever after more sexy appenders that do stuff.

Answer (score 4):

Logback is slf4j implementation providing lots of configurable appenders.
http://logback.qos.ch/

It provides Context based logging, events, and extensive filtering of log events.
You can with little effort extend basic filters with your own to suit your needs.

Details here:
http://logback.qos.ch/manual/filters.html

Comment: Filters are not conversation aware, they only work on anindividual message/event.

Comment: But I think it's rather easy to achieve that. Just extend existing appender to make it buffer output and then write or clear it. Throw in context awareness (http://logback.qos.ch/manual/loggingSeparation.html) which can be request related...

Comment: @JW, i know i could write everything myuself, but that defeats the benefits of asking for foss libraries.